# Loop that will run 20 times for array with two entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can I run a loop 20 times for an array that have only two entries?

I have the following code

```js
const genders = ['male', 'female'];

const randChoice = arr => {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};

const loop = () =>
  for (let i = ''; i <= 20; i++) {
    const data = randChoice(genders);
    if(data === 'male') {
  const name = randChoice(maleNames);
  people.push(new Data(data, name, lastName))
} else {
  const name = randChoice(femaleNames);
  people.push(new Data(data, name, lastName))
}
console.log('people', people)
return people;
```

I have tried some different things but never get it working and looping 20 times.

thanksa for all answers.

But let make this more complex
in thisd case. This will not work

Comment: You probably want `let i = 0` in your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is at Line 8, when you wrote `for (let i = ''; i <= 20; i++)`, you need to first set the variable *i* to 0, like this: `for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++)`.

The whole code for your loop will then be:

```java
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const data = randChoice(genders);
    // here goes if else statement for gender
}
```

Another mistake that also *@Hasan Balcı* has pointed out, is that in your code, the loop runs 21 times instead of 20. Why? Because the variable *i* starts from 0, and the loop runs until it reaches 20, **including when its value is 20!**

To correct this, instead of writing `for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++)`, it will have to be `for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)`, changing `i <= 20` to `i < 20`!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Your loop iterates 21 times.

Comment: thanks. how about after edit. this will not run 20 times

Comment: yes! now it does run 20 times! (the code is correct)

Answer (score 2):

Like this you can iterate loop for 20 times:

```
const loop = () =>{
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const data = randChoice(genders);
    console.log(data);
  }}
```

Comment: Your loop iterates 21 times